# Make part of relativeLayout scrollable?

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a `relativeLayout` inside a `linearLayout`. `relativeLayout` contains buttons on the left, and a terminal&edittext on the right. I want only part of this `relativeLayout` to be scrollable, the buttons on the left. However If I try to do this the whole thing becomes scrollable. If I separate the buttons on the left from the terminal on the right, into two different relativeLayouts, the buttons become scrollable but the terminal and edittext now appear below the buttons instead of to the right of them.
Current screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHxc8.png

How do i jsut make the buttons scroll while keeping the terminal where it is? Why do the relative commands to be below/to the right of buttons not work if I separate them into two different `relativeLayouts`?

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topButtons" 
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/deviceConnect"
            android:layout_margin="8dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Connect"/>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Connected Adapter:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/deviceSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/currentSettings" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                    android:text="Current Settings: Not Connected"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Baud:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/baudSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Data:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/dataSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Parity:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/paritySpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Stop:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/stopSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button android:id="@+id/updateSettings"
            android:layout_margin="8dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Update\nSettings"/>
    </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enable"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Configure"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command2"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Version"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command3"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Run"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command4"/> 

        <Button android:id="@+id/Command6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Backspace"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command5"/> 

            <Button android:id="@+id/Command7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Backspace2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command6"/> 


        <jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView
        android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deviceConnect"
         android:layout_above="@+id/term_entry"  />

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/term_entry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command7" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/term_entry_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/entry_send"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/term_entry" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7gWP.png

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topButtons" 
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/deviceConnect"
            android:layout_margin="8dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Connect"/>
        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:text="Connected Adapter:"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                <Spinner android:id="@+id/deviceSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                <TextView android:id="@+id/currentSettings" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                    android:text="Current Settings: Not Connected"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Baud:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/baudSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Data:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/dataSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Parity:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/paritySpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_margin="8dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    <TextView android:text="Stop:"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <Spinner android:id="@+id/stopSpinner"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button android:id="@+id/updateSettings"
            android:layout_margin="8dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Update\nSettings"/>
    </LinearLayout>

       <ScrollView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enable"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Configure"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command2"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Version"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command3"/> 

       <Button android:id="@+id/Command5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Show Run"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command4"/> 

        <Button android:id="@+id/Command6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Backspace"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command5"/> 

         <Button android:id="@+id/Command7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:layout_below="@+id/Command6"/> 


        </RelativeLayout>  
</ScrollView>
         <RelativeLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView
        android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/deviceConnect"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deviceConnect"
         android:layout_above="@+id/term_entry"  />

         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/term_entry"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
            android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Command4" />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/term_entry_send"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/entry_send"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/term_entry" 
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            />

        </RelativeLayout>  

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want Enable-backspace2 in scrollbar?

Comment: how do you mean? i want all the buttons on the left in the scroll bar? sorry for the bad indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topButtons"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="4dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deviceConnect"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Connect" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Connected Adapter:" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/deviceSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/currentSettings"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dip"
                android:text="Current Settings: Not Connected" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Baud:" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/baudSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Data:" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/dataSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Parity:" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/paritySpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Stop:" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/stopSpinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/updateSettings"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="Update\nSettings" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrllyout"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rltvlyout"
            android:layout_width="100dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Command"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enable" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Command2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Command"
                android:text="Configure" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Command3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Command2"
                android:text="Exit" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Command4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Command3"
                android:text="Show Version" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Command5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Command4"
                android:text="Show Run" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Command6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Command5"
                android:text="Backspace" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Command7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/Command6"
                android:text="Backspace2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView
        android:id="@+id/emulatorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/term_entry"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deviceConnect"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrllyout"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/term_entry"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrllyout"
        android:imeOptions="actionNone|flagNoExtractUi"
        android:inputType="text|textImeMultiLine"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/term_entry_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/term_entry"
        android:text="@string/entry_send" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

use 
        `<scrollview>
        <view>
        <childs>
        </childs>
        </view>
        <scrollview>`

Comment: How do I separate children? I did <scrollview> <realativelayout> </relativelayout> </scrollview> but if I got an ewrror saying multiple children if I separate them.

Comment: use the childrens inside relative layout bcz scrollview can directly have only one child.

Comment: this only seems to scroll the whole relativelayout, not just the buttons. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: if I jsut put the buttons in one layout and scroll through them, the new layout with the terminal is only below the old layout, it will not go beside it.

Comment: i put up new code, this is my code where the terminal appears under the first relativeview, not on the right of it.

Comment: you need to take two different layouts one is for terminal and other is for buttons on the left of terminal layout and the one you have taken for buttons should be a direct child of scrollview.

Comment: I did that, the buttons scroll well but the other layout will not go to the right of them. :( I put up a  screenshot